# iOS load different image based on content scale

Tags: ios, iphone, filesystems, image-scaling

So I am trying to change the directory in which to load an image from based upon what content scale I should be at but I cannot figure out how to load the same image name from different directories.

```
int m_contentScale = [GameController getContentScale];
NSLog(@"%i", m_contentScale);
NSString* contentScalePath;
NSString* combinedPath;
CGImageRef imageReference;
do{
    switch (m_contentScale) {
        case 1:
            contentScalePath = @"Rush Racing/Resources/Images/SD/";
            break;
        case 2:
            contentScalePath = @"Rush Racing/Resources/Images/HD/";
            break;
        case 3:
            contentScalePath = @"/Rush Racing/Resources/Images/XHD/";
            break;
        case 4:
            contentScalePath = @"Rush Racing/Resources/Images/XXHD/";
            break;

        default:
            contentScalePath = @"Rush Racing/Resources/Images/SD/";
            break;
    }
    combinedPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], contentScalePath, path];
    NSLog(@"%@", combinedPath);
    imageReference = [[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:combinedPath] CGImage];

    //if it gets to the SD folder and still cant find a suitable graphic it will search globally for the graphic.
    if((m_contentScale == 1) && (imageReference == nil)){
        imageReference = [[UIImage imageNamed:path] CGImage];
        if(!imageReference) break;
    }
    if(m_contentScale > 1) m_contentScale--;//reduce content scale so it will go through all the folders
    //smaller than it until it finds the graphic it is looking for.
}while(imageReference == nil);
```

My file structure looks like this:[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rflkR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create your folder structure in finder, with same image names 
[image: finder directory structure]
2) Drag root folder (Images) add to project as **Create folder references** 
[image: add files alert]
[image: final project structure]
3) Use following extension or modify yourself as your needs

```
extension UIImage {
    convenience init?(named: String, contentScale: String) {
        guard let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath else { return nil }
        let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            .appendingPathComponent("Images")
            .appendingPathComponent(contentScale)
            .appendingPathComponent(named)
        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: fileUrl) else { return nil }
        self.init(data: data)
    }
}
```

3) Use it like

```
let img = UIImage(named: "Blue-Speaker.png", contentScale: "HD")
let img2 = UIImage(named: "Blue-Speaker.png", contentScale: "SD")
```